# Year picker without dates and months

Tags: reactjs, calendar, antd

Just need a dropdown to pick just year without any dates or months .. any suggestions how to get only year with calendar layout? In ant framework I can get year with month.

Answer (score 3):

Form the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#Common-API), you can add `mode` as given below:

```
<DatePicker onChange={onChange} mode="year" />
```

You can check the [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vy2425q9z0).

Comment: getting the year dropdown but not able to select the values

Comment: @ReNinja For that, you need to update ant-design version as stated [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/14371).

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani  value not bind